# Angular JS service prototype - why not return new() instead of using factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I follow [Object-oriented AngularJS Services](http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2014/02/14/angularjs-services-inheritance/) article to implement some OOP in my Angular JS services. Author of this article uses first `factory` then injects it to `service` - but why not return `new()` object already from `factory` or `service`?
Like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @param $http
 * @returns {CommunicationServiceImpl}
 * @constructor
 */
function CommunicationService($http){
    'use strict';

    /**
     * 
     * @constructor
     */
    function CommunicationServiceImpl(){

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param {string} path
     * @param {number} id
     * * @returns {*|Object|HttpPromise|{}|{method, params, headers}}
     */
    CommunicationServiceImpl.prototype.getById = function(path, id) {
        //return suitable promise etc...
    };

    return new CommunicationServiceImpl();
}
```

And in `app.js`:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('application')
        .factory('CommunicationService',
            [
                '$http',
                CommunicationService
            ]
        );
})(angular);
```

It seems to work very well for me, and in my opinion this way is much simpler, except I don't know something important about Angular JS services/factories. Am I right, or am I wrong and it needs to be done as article says? Thank you in advance for every answer.

Comment: Matter of preference.  I use John Papa style guide revealing module pattern and both your example and the one from the article hurt my eyes.

Comment: There is absolutely zero reason to use a constructor and a prototype if you are going to instantiate a singleton from it. Just make it an object literal.

Comment: One problem will be that the same service used elsewhere will be a different instance when it is supposed to be a singleton